Solidworks API moving components
I'm trying to use transform on a list of component2, but when I move a component in one list, the components in the other list move also:
private double[][] transform2ProssedPartAndGetCache(List<Component2> processedPart, double[] explosionDirection, IMathUtility mathUtility)
{
    int counter = 0;
    double[][] cacheTransform = new double[processedPart.Count][];

    foreach (Component2 component in processedPart)
    {
        cacheTransform[counter] = component.Transform2.ArrayData;
        double[] transformArray = component.Transform2.ArrayData;
        double explosionMagnitude = 0.085;
        transformArray[9] += explosionDirection[0] * explosionMagnitude;
        transformArray[10] += explosionDirection[1] * explosionMagnitude;
        transformArray[11] += explosionDirection[2] * explosionMagnitude;
        MathTransform newTransform = mathUtility.CreateTransform(transformArray);
        component.Transform2 = newTransform;
        counter++;
    }

    return cacheTransform;
}

This is where the function is called:
public string ExportStepResultImages(string subAssyParentName, string[] primaryProcessPartArr, string[] secondaryProcessPartArr)
{
    string exportPath = "C:\\SolidworksAPI";
    object[] tempComponents = swAssembly.GetComponents(true);
    Component2[] allComponents = tempComponents.Cast<Component2>().ToArray();
    double[] assemblyBbox = null;
    List<Component2> primaryprocessParts = null;
    List<Component2> secondaryProcessParts = null;

    if (subAssyParentName == null) // Sub-assy is the root
    {
        assemblyBbox = swAssembly.GetBox((int)swBoundingBoxOptions_e.swBoundingBoxIncludeRefPlanes);
        primaryprocessParts = OrderProcessPartComponents(allComponents, primaryProcessPartArr);
        if(secondaryProcessPartArr.Length > 0)
            secondaryProcessParts = OrderProcessPartComponents(allComponents, secondaryProcessPartArr);
    }
    else
    {
        Component2 subAssy = GetSubAssyComp(subAssyParentName, allComponents);

        if (subAssy == null)
            throw new Exception("could not find sub assembly");

        // TODO: need to set subAssy as flexible
        object[] subAssyChildrenObj = subAssy.GetChildren();
        Component2[] subAssyChildren = subAssyChildrenObj.Select(c => (Component2)c).ToArray();
        primaryprocessParts = OrderProcessPartComponents(subAssyChildren, primaryProcessPartArr);

        if (secondaryProcessPartArr.Length > 0)
            secondaryProcessParts = OrderProcessPartComponents(subAssyChildren, secondaryProcessPartArr);

        assemblyBbox = subAssy.GetBox(false, false);
    }

    dynamic result =  SnapshotStepResult(primaryprocessParts, secondaryProcessParts, assemblyBbox, exportPath);
}

The processedPart that is sent to the function is one of 2, specifically the secondaryProcessedPart.
But for some reason, the primaryProcessedPart components also move.
Note: This happens when they are under the same sub assembly in the CAD:
CAD tree image
But when they are the last sub assembly it works fine:
CAD tree image

"prossed" ?!? Do you mean processed ?

yes i mean processed

You're applying the transform to component at the end of the loop. The IComponent2 object is a pointer to the actual item in the Solidworks UI. It doesn't matter if you copy it to another list, it's still the same underlying object. Essentially, you're telling it to transform the component in the UI at the end of your by setting its Transform2.

@bigcrazyal iv updated the post. as you can see im only sending one of the 2 lists.
there are diffrent components in each list.
but they are under the same sub assembly.
